# Repeater lose model definition after parsing child if statement

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I've the following sample code:

```
Item {
    id: container

    property bool leftOptionEnabled: false
    property bool rightOptionEnabled: false

    property string leftOptionText: ""
    property string rightOptionText: ""

    signal leftOptionPressed()
    signal rightOptionPressed()

    Grid {
        columns: 3

        Repeater {
            model: [
                { value: "1", offset: 1 },
                { value: "2", offset: 0 },
                { value: "3", offset: 1 },
                { value: "4", offset: 1 },
                { value: "5", offset: 0 },
                { value: "6", offset: 2 },
                { value: "7", offset: 1 },
                { value: "8", offset: 0 },
                { value: "9", offset: 1 },
                { value: "", offset: container.leftOptionEnabled && container.leftOptionText ? 1 : 0 },
                { value: "0", offset: 0 },
                { value: "", offset: container.rightOptionEnabled && container.rightOptionText ? 2 : 0}
            ]

            delegate: Item {
                id: something
                width: 200
                height: 200

                Text {
                  anchors.centerIn: parent
                  text: model.value
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent

                    onPressed: {
                        if (model.index === 9)
                            container.leftOptionPressed();

                        if (model.index === 11)
                            container.rightOptionPressed();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `onPressed` signal of the `MouseArea` stop working as expected if I dynamically add a leftOption (so `leftOptionText` + `leftOptionEnabled`) and a rightOption and then I trigger the click for the left one.

What happen is that I get a this error: `ReferenceError: model is not defined`.

I cannot access either `index` or `model` after the first `if`, `modelData` is available.

Checking the presence of `model` via `console.log` (from `onModelChanged` for instance) does not show any anomaly, as expected, and I managed to find a workaround by returning the signals instead of just calling them.

Even if the workaround get me exactly where I need, I still would like to understand why the error happen and how to actually prevent it without "tricks".

Anyone can help me understand the issue? Is this a bug?

Comment: Never seen 'model.index' construct before. Does it work with 'index'?

Comment: Hm...your example is working fine for me. Could you please post an example which does not work for you? I am confused if you have already applied your "workaround" in your example.

Comment: @sk2212 this is the nonworking example, to trigger the bug just add some minimal code (like a `Text`) and externally valorize both left and right options text, then click on the left one, this was done with qt 5.9, maybe the problem does not arise with the newest 5.10

Comment: @Matteo This is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @BenjaminT I added the incredibly complex `Text` node that complete the example. If you still cannot try it you might want to avoid QML questions :X

Comment: @Matteo It is not a matter of being able to try it. If you want people to help you, you have to help them help you. And are your sure you example is minimal and cannot be simplified?

Comment: @BenjaminT If I strip more code, I would have to rewrite it completely to adapt the index numbers to the situation, eventually removing the chance to see the problem. This is the minimal version I tested and that was still producing the issue. If you think you can simplify it, please feel free to edit the question, I'll gladly try it again myself.

Comment: Well, your `Repeater` component is not really useful in this case because the item will be painted on the same position at all time. So at least you should wrap the `Repeater` component in a `Column`.

Comment: @sk2212 My bad, there is a `Grid` that wrap the `Repeater`, i'll fix the question.